# Best Practices: Using Method Parameters to create XPath String

Tags: selenium, page-factory

This is my first time posting a question, so bear with me (and/or provide constructive criticism) if I'm not following etiquette/best practices for StackExchange, or if I just generally say something wrong. I'm currently working on a personal Selenium project that tests portions of a website for a mobile game. In the game, there are several classes (such as Knight, Mage, etc.), and I have noticed that the XPaths for most of the objects on the website use these names to reference the object, leading to several similar XPaths, which only vary by the one word.

Example:

```
    By knightImage = By.xpath("//img[contains(text(), 'Knight Hero')]");
    By mageImage = By.xpath("//img[contains(text(), 'Mage Hero')]");
```

My initial response to this has been to create methods that use the character class names as inputs and construct the xpaths within.

Example:

```
    public void selectHero(String heroClassName) {

        By selectedHero = By.xpath("//img[contains(text(), '"
            + heroClassName + " Hero')]");
        driver.findElement(selectedHero).click();
    }
```

This method allows a lot of my code to be reusable, but I'm concerned that this could make the program less clean, since the objects on the page aren't assigned to specific variables. Is there a way to handle page objects with similar XPaths using PageFactory, or is it better to treat each of these page objects as a different WebElement variable and create separate methods for each?

Example

```
    public class HeroPage() {

        @FindBy(xpath = "//img[contains(text(), 'Knight Hero')]")
        private WebElement knightImage;

        @FindBy(xpath = "//img[contains(text(), 'Mage Hero')]")
        private WebElement mageImage;

        public HeroPage(WebDriver driver) {
            super(driver);
        }

        public void selectKnight() {
            knightImage.click();
        }

        public void selectMage() {
            mageImage.click();
        }

    }
```

Comment: another community that might have input on this is https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (forgive my ignorance...  i'm not sure if you can "migrate" this over there, or whether you would be penalized for double-posting)

Comment: If you decide to go the route of page factory, you will lose the ability to have variables in your locators, as they are required to be known values at compile-time (constants).  I have found this to only be a minor inconvenience in my experience and prefer to stick with page factory, but your mileage may vary.  There are always ways to work around the limitations depending on the situation(s).

Comment: Your question asks for opinion-based answers, which is normally frowned upon at SO; see the article https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for more information. Having said that, I have personally used both approaches in the past, even in the same page class. If there are only two classes, I would probably got with defining them as two WebElements. If there were more, I would probably go with something like your selectHero() method.

Comment: @pestophagous https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ accepts only error-less program/scripts for Review. Nothing less than that